# Extract files from ZIP file with VBScript

Tags: vbscript, zip

When extracting files from a ZIP file I was using the following.

```
Sub Unzip(strFile)
' This routine unzips a file. NOTE: The files are extracted to a folder '
' in the same location using the name of the file minus the extension.  '
' EX. C:\Test.zip will be extracted to C:\Test '
'strFile (String) = Full path and filename of the file to be unzipped. '
Dim arrFile
    arrFile = Split(strFile, ".")
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    fso.CreateFolder(arrFile(0) & "\ ")
    pathToZipFile= arrFile(0) & ".zip"
    extractTo= arrFile(0) & "\ "
    set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    set filesInzip=objShell.NameSpace(pathToZipFile).items
    objShell.NameSpace(extractTo).CopyHere(filesInzip)
    fso.DeleteFile pathToZipFile, True
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set objShell = Nothing
End Sub 'Unzip
```

This was working, but now I get a "The File Exists" Error.

What is the reason for this? Are there any alternatives?

Comment: @Tester101 Please mark one of the responses as an answer or answer it yourself. Thank you

Answer (score 9):

All above solutions are accurate, but they are not definitive.

If you are trying to extract a *zipped file* into a temporary folder, a folder that displays "Temporary Folder For YOURFILE.zip" will immediately be created (in `C:\Documents` and `Settings\USERNAME\Local Settings\Temp`) for **EACH FILE** contained within your ZIP file, which you are trying to extract.

That's right, if you have 50 files, it will create 50 folders within your temp directory.

**But** if you have 200 files, it will stop at 99 and crash stating - **The File Exists**.

..

Apparently, this does not occur on Windows 7 with the contributions I view above. But regardless, we can still have checks. Alright, so this is how you fix it:

```
    '========================
    'Sub: UnzipFiles
    'Language: vbscript
    'Usage: UnzipFiles("C:\dir", "extract.zip")
    'Definition: UnzipFiles([Directory where zip is located & where files will be extracted], [zip file name])
    '========================
    Sub UnzipFiles(folder, file)
        Dim sa, filesInzip, zfile, fso, i : i = 1
        Set sa = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
            Set filesInzip=sa.NameSpace(folder&file).items
        For Each zfile In filesInzip
            If Not fso.FileExists(folder & zfile) Then
                sa.NameSpace(folder).CopyHere(zfile), &H100 
                i = i + 1
            End If
            If i = 99 Then
            zCleanup(file, i)
            i = 1
            End If
        Next
        If i > 1 Then 
            zCleanup(file, i)
        End If
        fso.DeleteFile(folder&file)
    End Sub

    '========================
    'Sub: zCleanup
    'Language: vbscript
    'Usage: zCleanup("filename.zip", 4)
    'Definition: zCleanup([Filename of Zip previously extracted], [Number of files within zip container])
    '========================
    Sub zCleanUp(file, count)   
        'Clean up
        Dim i, fso
        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        For i = 1 To count
           If fso.FolderExists(fso.GetSpecialFolder(2) & "\Temporary Directory " & i & " for " & file) = True Then
           text = fso.DeleteFolder(fso.GetSpecialFolder(2) & "\Temporary Directory " & i & " for " & file, True)
           Else
              Exit For
           End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

And that's it, copy and paste those two functions into your VBScript hosted program and you should be good to go, on Windows XP & Windows 7.

Thanks!

Comment: nice code for cleaning up; thanks! fso.GetSpecialFolder(TemporaryFolder) will be even nicer :)

Comment: I had a lot of trouble with this until I started using full, absolute paths. ".\zipfile.zip" did not work at all for me.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com) from VBScript.

To unpack an existing zipfile, overwriting any files that may exist:

```
WScript.echo("Instantiating a ZipFile object...")
Dim zip 
Set zip = CreateObject("Ionic.Zip.ZipFile")

WScript.echo("Initialize (Read)...")
zip.Initialize("C:\Temp\ZipFile-created-from-VBScript.zip")

WScript.echo("setting the password for extraction...")
zip.Password = "This is the Password."

' set the default action for extracting an existing file
' 0 = throw exception
' 1 = overwrite silently
' 2 = don't overwrite (silently)
' 3 = invoke the ExtractProgress event
zip.ExtractExistingFile = 1

WScript.echo("extracting all files...")
Call zip.ExtractAll("extract")

WScript.echo("Disposing...")
zip.Dispose()

WScript.echo("Done.")
```

To create a new zipfile:

```
dim filename 
filename = "C:\temp\ZipFile-created-from-VBScript.zip"

WScript.echo("Instantiating a ZipFile object...")
dim zip2 
set zip2 = CreateObject("Ionic.Zip.ZipFile")

WScript.echo("using AES256 encryption...")
zip2.Encryption = 3

WScript.echo("setting the password...")
zip2.Password = "This is the Password."

WScript.echo("adding a selection of files...")
zip2.AddSelectedFiles("*.js")
zip2.AddSelectedFiles("*.vbs")

WScript.echo("setting the save name...")
zip2.Name = filename

WScript.echo("Saving...")
zip2.Save()

WScript.echo("Disposing...")
zip2.Dispose()

WScript.echo("Done.")
```

Answer (score 3):

There's answers above which are perfectly correct, but I thought I'd wrap everything up into a full solution that I'm using:

```
strZipFile = "test.zip"     'name of zip file
outFolder = "."             'destination folder of unzipped files (must exist)
'If using full paths rather than relative to the script, comment the next line
pwd = Replace(WScript.ScriptFullName, WScript.ScriptName, "")

Set objShell = CreateObject( "Shell.Application" )
Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(pwd+strZipFile).Items()
Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(pwd+outFolder)
intOptions = 256
objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptions

'Clean up
Set WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
tempfolder = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%temp%")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Call fso.DeleteFolder(tempfolder + "\Temporary Directory 1 for " + strZipFile, True )
```

Answer (score 2):

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Visual_Basic/VB_Script/Q_23022290.html

Check your temp directory. If you have 99 folders associated with this unzipping process, try deleting them.

Answer (score 2):

I added the following code to the beginning of my unzip procedure to delete these directories before I unzip:

```
For i = 1 To 99
  If aqFileSystem.Exists(GetAppPath("Local Settings", "") & "\Temp\Temporary Directory " & i & " for DialogState.zip") = True Then
      result = aqFileSystem.ChangeAttributes(GetAppPath("Local Settings", "") & "\Temp\Temporary Directory " & i & " for DialogState.zip", 1 OR 2, aqFileSystem.fattrFree) 
      Call DelFolder(GetAppPath("Local Settings", "") & "\Temp\Temporary Directory " & i & " for DialogState.zip")  
   Else
      Exit For
   End If
Next
```