# How to deal with zip file?

Tags: c#, .net

I have zip file and I want to know which library can handle it? Is there built-in method in the.netframework can unzip zip file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SharpZipLib is a good choice to use with ZIP files in .NET.

See https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib or http://icsharpcode.github.io/SharpZipLib/ for more information.

Comment: I've used this in a few projects and had no problems.  Simple and straightfoward.  As an aside, it's GPL I think.

Comment: +1 Works perfectly! Here the link to the simplest example http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/SharpZipLib_FastZip.ashx

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.deflatestream.aspx) class to unzip your file. There's an example there, too.

Comment: -1 decompressing a stream is not the same as unpacking a zip archive. From the documentation you linked: *"This class does not inherently provide functionality for adding files to or extracting files from .zip archives."*

Comment: -1 ZIP is a collection of files, like .tar.gz in unix is, not just a stream like a .gz.

Answer (score 4):

Use either `GZipStream` or `DeflateStream` in `System.IO.Compression`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.deflatestream.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx

`GZipStream` is similar to `DeflateStream`, but contains a few extra bits to make it friendly with applications like WinZip.

Comment: Can those library handle the zip file which contains multiple files and folders?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/), created by [Cheeso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/48082/cheeso). See also this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507751/extracting-files-from-a-zip-archive-programmatically-using-c-and-system-io-packa/531206#531206).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this: [Free compression library for C# which supports 7zip (LZMA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449998/free-compression-library-for-c-which-supports-7zip-lzma)