# Create Compressed Folder UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, zip

Create Compressed Folder

I would like to zip a folder, I tried to write code that should do this, but I am getting an error that the folder is empty :

1. Create the empty zip file.
2. It does not allow me to extract the files from the zip file (*It
   tells me that, in fact, that the folder is empty*).

**MainPage.xaml**:

```
<Grid>
   <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
       <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5">
           <Button x:Name="BtnChooseFolder" Click="BtnChooseFolder_Click" Content="Choose Folder" Margin="5"/>
           <TextBlock Text="Folder to Zip: " VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
           <TextBlock x:Name="TxbFolderToZip" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
       </StackPanel>
       <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5">
           <Button x:Name="BtnChooseDestination" Click="BtnChooseDestination_Click" Content="Choose Destination" Margin="5"/>
           <TextBlock Text="Zip Folder: " VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
           <TextBlock x:Name="TxbZipFolder" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
       </StackPanel>
       <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
           <Button x:Name="BtnZip" Click="BtnZip_Click" Content="Zippa" Margin="10"/>
           <TextBlock x:Name="TxbPercentage" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
       </StackPanel>
   </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**:

```
string FolderPathOne = string.Empty;
string FoldeDestinationOne = string.Empty;

StorageFolder FolderPath;
StorageFolder DestinationPath;

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
}

private async void BtnChooseFolder_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FolderPicker FolderPickFol = new FolderPicker();
    FolderPickFol.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop;
    FolderPickFol.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
    StorageFolder SelectFolderToZipa = await FolderPickFol.PickSingleFolderAsync();
    StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace("PickedFolder", SelectFolderToZipa);
    FolderPath = SelectFolderToZipa;
    FolderPathOne = SelectFolderToZipa.Path;
    TxbFolderToZip.Text = FolderPathOne;
}

private async void BtnChooseDestination_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FolderPicker FolderPickFol = new FolderPicker();
    FolderPickFol.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop;
    FolderPickFol.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
    StorageFolder SelectFolderToZipa = await FolderPickFol.PickSingleFolderAsync();
    StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace("PickedDestination", SelectFolderToZipa);
    DestinationPath = SelectFolderToZipa;
    FoldeDestinationOne = SelectFolderToZipa.Path;
    TxbZipFolder.Text = FoldeDestinationOne;
}

private async void BtnZip_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StorageFile zipFile = await DestinationPath.CreateFileAsync("ZipFolderTest.zip", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    Stream zipToCreate = await zipFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();
    ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(zipToCreate, ZipArchiveMode.Update);

    await ZipFolderContents(FolderPath, archive, FolderPath.Path);
}

private async Task ZipFolderContents(StorageFolder sourceFolder, ZipArchive archive, string sourceFolderPath)
{
    IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files = await sourceFolder.GetFilesAsync();
    foreach (StorageFile file in files)
    {
        ZipArchiveEntry readmeEntry = archive.CreateEntry(file.Path.Remove(0, sourceFolderPath.Length));
        byte[] buffer = WindowsRuntimeBufferExtensions.ToArray(await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file));
        using (Stream entryStream = readmeEntry.Open())
        {
            await entryStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

> Although there is writing in the stream, it creates the empty and inaccessible file.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your scenario, you could use `ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory` method to compress folder directly.

```
string DestinationFolderPath = string.Empty;
string SourceFolderPath = string.Empty;

StorageFolder SourceFolder;
StorageFolder DestinationFolder;

private async void BtnChooseFolder_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FolderPicker FolderPickFol = new FolderPicker();
    FolderPickFol.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop;
    FolderPickFol.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
    Windows.Storage.StorageFolder SelectFolderToZipa = await FolderPickFol.PickSingleFolderAsync();
    StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace("PickedFolder", SelectFolderToZipa);
    SourceFolder = SelectFolderToZipa;
    SourceFolderPath = SelectFolderToZipa.Path;
    TxbFolderToZip.Text = SourceFolderPath;
}

private async void BtnChooseDestination_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FolderPicker FolderPickFol = new FolderPicker();
    FolderPickFol.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop;
    FolderPickFol.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
    StorageFolder SelectFolderToZipa = await FolderPickFol.PickSingleFolderAsync();
    StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace("PickedDestination", SelectFolderToZipa);
    DestinationFolder = SelectFolderToZipa;
    DestinationFolderPath = SelectFolderToZipa.Path;
    TxbZipFolder.Text = DestinationFolderPath;
}

private async void BtnZip_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    if (SourceFolder != null)
    {

        StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace("PickedFolderToken", SourceFolder);
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            try
            {

                System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(SourceFolderPath, $"{DestinationFolderPath}\\{SourceFolder.Name}.zip");

            }
            catch (Exception w)
            {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

For this method, you just pass the source folder path and the destination zip file 
two parameters.

```
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(SourceFolderPath, $"{DestinationFolderPath}\\{SourceFolder.Name}.zip");
```

The above code is edited base on your post, you could use it directly in your project.

**Update**

Derive from this [case](https://stackoverrun.com/cn/q/11979983).

> This System.ArgumentException is thrown from the `WindowsRuntimeBufferExtensions` ToArray method, which expects that the IBuffer's size is larger than 0.

So I replace it with the follow method

```
private async Task ZipFolderContentsHelper(StorageFolder sourceFolder, ZipArchive archive, string sourceFolderPath)
{
    IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files = await sourceFolder.GetFilesAsync();

    foreach (StorageFile file in files)
    {
        var path = file.Path.Remove(0, sourceFolderPath.Length);
        ZipArchiveEntry readmeEntry = archive.CreateEntry(file.Path.Remove(0, sourceFolderPath.Length));
        ulong fileSize = (await file.GetBasicPropertiesAsync()).Size;
        byte[] buffer = fileSize > 0 ? (await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file)).ToArray()
        : new byte[0];


        using (Stream entryStream = readmeEntry.Open())
        {
            await entryStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
    }

    IReadOnlyList<StorageFolder> subFolders = await sourceFolder.GetFoldersAsync();

    if (subFolders.Count() == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    foreach (StorageFolder subfolder in subFolders)
    {
        await ZipFolderContentsHelper(subfolder, archive, sourceFolderPath);
    }
}
```

This is [code sample](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/ZipFile.git) that you could use directly.

Comment: I knew this method ... I wanted to use the stream, as in my example, because I wanted the completed bytes to display the percentage.

Comment: Have you check this [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36738028/7254781).

Comment: In this example, there is how to extract them, but if I try to adapt it to make them compress it is not clear how to do it.

Comment: @Jimmy , I solved issue and update reply. for better understanding, I uploaded the code sample.

Comment: Thanks...! Work perfectly .. But how can the percentage be calculated?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT, the result zip file doesn't contain hidden files, hidden folders, .lnk, .url files of the source, while zipping the other files correctly. Any solution?