# Vbs Script to check if a folder exist and then run a file

Tags: vbscript, filesystems

Hello I'm new here I need a script to check, if a folder exist and then run a file from the folder. If not, it should extract a ZIP file into a specific location. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Gimme da codez questions are not welcome here on SO.

Answer (score 28):

```
'Objects
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set shl = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

path="C:\SomeFolderToExist\" 'path to folder    
exists = fso.FolderExists(path)

if (exists) then 
    program="myprog.exe" 'Program name to run
    shl.Run(path & program) 'Run a program
end if
```

For unzipping, I can only tell you to see this: [Extract files from ZIP file with VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291406/extract-files-from-zip-file-with-vbscript)

Comment: I tried this but it's not working                                                                             Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set shl = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Path = "C:\SYSTEM TOOLS\"
Exists = fso.FolderExists(Path)

If (Exists) Then
    program = "HWMonitor.exe"
    shl.Run ("C:\SYSTEM TOOLS\HWMonitor.exe")
End If

Answer (score -3):

```
Dim FILE, tmpfilepath, uniqueid As String
    uniqueid = Row.uniqueid
    tmpfilepath = "G:\Files\" + uniqueid
    If System.IO.Directory.Exists(tmpfilepath) Then
          do something
              Else
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(tmpfilepath)


    End If
```

Comment: How is this different/better than the several answers already posted?

Comment: This is not VBScript.

Answer (score -5):

If I understand correctly :
create a script: `sudo vim script.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
    echo "enter your path"
    read path

    if [[ -d "$path"  ]]
            then
            echo $(sudo $path/yourprograme)
            else
            echo "enter your specific location"
            read spec
            $ mkdir -p $spec
            $ unzip yourfiles.zip -d $spec

            fi
```

run the scrip.sh  : `sudo ./script.sh`

Comment: This is not VBScript.