# How to create a folder named "1" (If not exists) then create a folder named "2" (if not exist in the same directory)and so on

Tags: vbscript

I need to create folders named like "1", "2" , "3"  and so on ...

Everytime script should check if it exists already or not. If not it should create or otherwise simply continue and create folder with next numeric value.

e.g. If folder "1" is there is shouldn't create folder, instead script should create folder "2" and exit. Everytime script should check for the folder and it should create the next one if its already there, or else it should create the same it was checking for.

Please let me know if anybody know the answer.

Regards,
Eshant Garg

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vbs Script to check if a folder exist and then run a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14121790/vbs-script-to-check-if-a-folder-exist-and-then-run-a-file)

Comment: When in doubt, [read the](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5xc78d8d%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kby5ae3%28v=vs.84%29.aspx).