# Check for a folder name, then print in CMD

Tags: vbscript

I can set the objective folder name and print it's contents using

```
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)
```

But is there a way to check if the folder exists then print the contents in command line?

Comment: Try `objFSO.FolderExists(objStartFolder)` ... a working example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14121790/vbs-script-to-check-if-a-folder-exist-and-then-run-a-file)