# How can I pass the argument in vbs

Tags: windows, vbscript

I'm a linux guy and new to windows, im trying to create a small vbs script to create bunch of folders.
Im trying to create a mainfolder according to user input and 4 subfolder in it with static names. I somehow got two seperate working scripts for mainfolder and subfolder but I would like to combine them both which means once the mainfolder is created as per user input next it should create  subfolders below that.

**Script which creates Mainfolder.vbs as per user input:**

```
strfolder = InputBox("Please enter a name for your new folder:")
set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objFSO.CreateFolder "C:\test\" & strfolder
```

**Script which creates subfolders.vbs folders:**

```
Option Explicit

dim wshShell
set wshShell = wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
DIM fSO

DIM foldername1
DIM foldername2
DIM foldername3
DIM foldername4

foldername1=("subfolder1")
foldername2=("subfolder2")
foldername3=("subfolder3")
foldername4=("subfolder4")

dim folderpath
SET FSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

folderpath = "C:\test" & _        
             "\" & foldername1
wscript.echo "Creating folder: " & folderpath
FSO.CREATEFOLDER(folderpath)

folderpath = "C:\test" & _            
             "\" & foldername2 
wscript.echo "Creating folder: " & folderpath
FSO.CREATEFOLDER(folderpath)

folderpath = "C:\test" & _
             "\" & foldername3 
wscript.echo "Creating folder: " & folderpath
FSO.CREATEFOLDER(folderpath) 

folderpath = "C:\test" & _
             "\" & foldername4 
wscript.echo "Creating folder: " & folderpath
FSO.CREATEFOLDER(folderpath)
```

In short, how can I create a mainfolder as per user input and subfolders with static names?

would like to combine these both and work together as a single script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this subroutine : ***SmartCreateFolder(strFolder)***

---

```
Sub SmartCreateFolder(strFolder)
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        If Not .FolderExists(strFolder) then
            SmartCreateFolder(.getparentfoldername(strFolder))
            .CreateFolder(strFolder)
        End If
    End With 
End Sub
```

---

The combined whole script can be written like that :

```
Option Explicit
Const Title = "SmartCreateFolder"
Const Time2Wait = 2
Dim ws,MainFolderPath,MainFolderName,SubFolderPath,Arr_SubFolder_Name,i
Set ws  = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
Arr_SubFolder_Name = Array("subfolder1","subfolder2","subfolder3","subfolder4")

MainfolderName = InputBox(_
"Please enter a name for your new folder :",Title,"Type the name here")
If MainfolderName = "" Then Wscript.Quit(1)

MainFolderPath = "C:\test\" & MainfolderName

For i=LBound(Arr_SubFolder_Name) To UBound(Arr_SubFolder_Name)
    Call SmartCreateFolder(MainFolderPath)
    SubFolderPath = MainFolderPath & "\" & Arr_SubFolder_Name(i)
    Call SmartCreateFolder(SubFolderPath) 
Next
ws.run "Explorer " & MainFolderPath
'---------------------------------------------------------------
Sub SmartCreateFolder(strFolder)
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        If Not .FolderExists(strFolder) then
            ws.Popup "Creating folder: " & StrFolder,Time2Wait,_
            Title,vbInformation+vbSystemModal
            SmartCreateFolder(.getparentfoldername(strFolder))
            .CreateFolder(strFolder)
        End If
    End With 
End Sub
'---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: @user692942 Answer is edited refer to your comment ! Thank you ! and  have a nice day !

Comment: Definitely a better approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. It works seamless. But it overwrites folder which exists. How can I add if condition to stop if folder exists?

Comment: @Vinoth by adding an `If` statement and [checking if the folder exists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14121914/692942).

Comment: @Vinoth Just to be clear the code dosen't overwrite folder which exists, but just repeating the MsgBox. Anyway, i tweaked the code above, just give a try and tell me the result ! So the code is edited in order to add a popup message only for creating new folders.

Comment: @Vinoth Please don't modify anything, just try it as it now ! i edited  and the testing if exists or not is located on subroutine ! i tested on my side and it worked 5/5

Comment: Thank you. It is not recreating the folder but still shows folder created pop ups though the folder is already exist, Is there a way to error out if folder exists?

Comment: adding an if condition was a old comment. please ignore it. thanks

Comment: @Vinoth Try out here : [SmartCreateFolder.vbs](https://pastebin.com/vJAYqS2S)

Comment: So finally it created a mainfolder and subfolders, also It opens existing folder if you try to create it. This looks great.. thank you @Hackoo

Comment: @Vinoth Great !! Please take Stack Overflow (SO) [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how to say thanks on SO by accepting an answer on being helpful by clicking on gray check mark symbol left to an answer.
See also [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/)
A question with no accepted answer is rated as a not answered question even if there are good answers.