# How to unzip a password-protected file in vbscript?

Tags: vbscript

I am fairly new to VBScript. I have done some extensive research on what I am trying to accomplish and have even found examples of what to do, but cannot get it to work properly.

In my perfect world, I need to unzip all zipped files sent to a folder from a third-party vendor, import the unzipped file into a different folder then delete the zipped file.

The script below works properly for non-password protected zip files, but all files sent from the vendor have passwords. As seen in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291406/extract-files-from-zip-file-with-vbscript), the following lines which I have commented out should insert the password but do not.  "`...(pwd+myZipfile)`" and "`...(pwd+extractTo)`".

Thank you in advanced for your help. Please suggest any code improvements or other methods to make this happen.

```
pathToZipFile = "P:\ZipFiles"  
extractTo = "P:\UnZip"    
Dim fso
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.GetFolder(pathToZipFile)
Set fc = f.Files
Dim myZipFile 
Dim intOptions, objShell, objSource, objTarget
Dim pwd
pwd = "password" 

For Each f1 in fc
On Error Resume Next

    myZipFile = f1

    '    Create the required Shell objects
    Set objShell = CreateObject( "Shell.Application" )

    '    Create a reference to the files and folders
    'Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(pwd+myZipFile).Items( ) 
    Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(myZipFile).Items( )

    '     Create a reference to the target folder
    Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(pwd+extractTo)
    Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(extractTo)
    intOptions = 256

    '     UnZIP the file
    objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptions

    '     Release the objects
    Set objSource = Nothing
    Set objTarget = Nothing
    Set objShell  = Nothing

    'Delete File from "P:\ZipFiles" after unzipping
    fso.DeleteFile f1, True

Next
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a closer look at the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6710371/1630171) from which the `pwd+...` came, you'll notice that `pwd` does *not* contain a *password*, but a *path*. The variable was probably named after the Unix command [`pwd`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pwd), which stands for "print working directory".

As far as I know the `Shell.Application` object does not support unpacking password-protected Zip files. [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/692498/1630171) to the question you referenced suggests the [DotNetZip library](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/). Or you could use [7-zip](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/sevenzip/7za920.zip):

```
Function qq(str)
  qq = Chr(34) & str & Chr(34)
End Function

zipfile  = "..."
password = "..."

Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sh.Run "7za.exe x " & qq(zipfile) & " -p" & qq(password), 0, True
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I had trouble getting the files to unzip using vbscript but found a solution using a windows batch file.