# Is there is any way to unzip the password protected pkzip files using vba

Tags: vba

Fname-"file need to unzip"

Dest_path-"path where fles need to be Stored after unzip"

```
Set oApp=CreateObject ("shell.application")
For each filename in oApp(Fname).items
    oApp.namespace(Dest_path).copyhere
Next
```

The above code is working fine for normal zip files..

Comment: Yes, if you know the password.

Comment: You probably need a command line tool. Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666282/how-to-unzip-a-password-protected-file-in-vbscript