# How to delete files from zip with VBScript

Tags: vbscript

Im very new to VBScript (this is my first time ever using it). So far I've copied and altered my way into getting as far as I am.

I have an APK file that is too big for my needs. So what I've been doing is manually changing it to a zip and then deleting a couple images from it then renaming it back to an APK. Im trying to automate that with a VBScript. So far I have

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
sFolder = WORKSPACE & "\temp\" & app & "\build\" & PLATFORMSUBFOLDER & "\dist\" & app & "\bin"
oShell.CurrentDirectory = sFolder 

'Make the Apk a Zip.
fso.MoveFile apkfile, zipApk
```

This is all working and I can see in Windows Explorer that the APK changes to a zip like I want it to. So Im wondering if there is any quick ways to just go in and delete a couple files without extracting the whole thing?

If not is there an easy way to extract the files and parse them at the same time?

Ive looked here [Extract files from ZIP file with VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291406/extract-files-from-zip-file-with-vbscript)
but cant seem to get it working. I keep getting error "Object required: 'objShell.Names(...)'" Any hints to why this is happening?

Comment: may be install [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) and use it in command line mode that vbs can execute in a shell? Some [description](http://sevenzip.sourceforge.jp/chm/cmdline/syntax.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`MoveHere`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787874%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method to move an item out of the zip file:

```
zipfile = "C:\path\to\your.zip"
fname   = "some.file"
dst     = "C:\some\folder"

Set app = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
For Each f In app.NameSpace(zipfile).Items
  If f.Name = fname Then
    app.Namespace(dst).MoveHere(f)
  End If
Next
```

Then delete the files from the `dst` folder:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
fso.DeleteFile fso.BuildPath(dst, fname), True
```

Comment: I wont get a chance to test this till Monday so I'll check back then but it looks like its exactly what I need if it works. Thanks!

Comment: Why this not working in windows xp it copy not move i don't know