# Remove files from .zip file with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am going to write a Powershell script to remove files from a .zip file. 
In my .zip file, I have 
test.txt (latest) 
test1.txt (older) 
test2.txt 
.... 
testN.txt (oldest), 
all with different file sizes (or in powershell, it's called Length). 
I want to keep only 2G or smaller of them and remove the rest. It is required to remove from the oldest ones. 
Since the .zip file may be very large. It's better not to extract it and zip again.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thank you so much.

Comment: What are you planning to use for Zipping? 3rd party tools? .Net classes?

Comment: I don't quite get your questions, sorry. The .zip file already exists at the server.

Comment: Powershell doesn't have built-in support for zip file management. You need some tool for handling the zips.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Thank you. Are there any tools you recommend? Any tutorials or documents about zipping? Thanks again.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Adopting [this VBScript solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20147320/1630171):

```psh
$zipfile = 'C:\path\to\your.zip'
$files   = 'some.file', 'other.file', ...
$dst     = 'C:\some\folder'

$app = New-Object -COM 'Shell.Application'
$app.NameSpace($zipfile).Items() | ? { $files -contains $_.Name } | % {
  $app.Namespace($dst).MoveHere($_)
  Remove-Item (Join-Path $dst $_.Name)
}
```

---

If you have .net Framework 4.5 installed, something like this should work, too:

```psh
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.IO.Compression')

$zipfile = 'C:\path\to\your.zip'
$files   = 'some.file', 'other.file', ...

$stream = New-Object IO.FileStream($zipfile, [IO.FileMode]::Open)
$mode   = [IO.Compression.ZipArchiveMode]::Update
$zip    = New-Object IO.Compression.ZipArchive($stream, $mode)

($zip.Entries | ? { $files -contains $_.Name }) | % { $_.Delete() }

$zip.Dispose()
$stream.Close()
$stream.Dispose()
```

The parentheses around filtering items from the `Entries` collection are required, because otherwise the subsequent `Delete()` would modify the collection. This would prevent reading (and thus deleting) other items from the collection. The resulting error message looks like this:

```
An error occurred while enumerating through a collection: Collection was modified;
enumeration operation may not execute..
At line:1 char:1
+ $zip.Entries | ? { $filesToRemove -contains $_.Name } | % { $_.Delete() }
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Collecti...ipArchiveEntry]:Enumerator) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadEnumeration
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/), a free Zip tool. A Technet [sample](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-and-7Zip-83020e74) illustrates how to create a zip archive with 7-Zip in Powershell.

Learn the proper commands to get a listing of your zip's contents and use the `d` command to delete files from within the archive.

Comment: I find this the most transparent option, even though it requires an external program.

Comment: you could've also added the actual snippet here, since in the end it's just a oneliner based on: `7z.exe d file.zip file-to-exclude`

Comment: This has no bearing on the question, it needs to be done programmatically, not with a 3rd party gui application.

Comment: @SpaceBear 7zip has a command-line interface. Nowadays, [Compress-Archve](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/compress-archive?view=powershell-7.2) would do, but that was introduced in [Powershell 5.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/windows-powershell/whats-new/what-s-new-in-windows-powershell-50?view=powershell-7.2) - three years after this Q.