# Delete a file from zip files in powershell 4

Tags: powershell

I have a function that is working fine. It extract zip file into a destination folder. If the destination folder contains files, it overwrite with the new extract files.Now I wanted to delete/remove one file (bigfile.txt) with a size of 12G before extracting the zip file. How will I do that. Can anyone help me please ? below is the function.  Thank you

```
function Unzip($zipfile, $outdir)
{
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
$archive = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead($zipfile)
foreach ($entry in $archive.Entries)
{
$entryTargetFilePath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($outdir, $entry.FullName)
$entryDir = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($entryTargetFilePath)
#Ensure the directory of the archive entry exists
if(!(Test-Path $entryDir )){
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $entryDir | Out-Null
}

#If the entry is not a directory entry, then extract entry
if(!$entryTargetFilePath.EndsWith("\")){
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::ExtractToFile($entry, $entryTargetFilePath, $true);
}

Unzip -zipfile "c:\temp\filezip_1.zip" -outdir "c:\folder_1\extracted_files"
Unzip -zipfile "c:\temp\filezip_2.zip" -outdir "c:\folder_2\extracted_files"e
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only showing your unzip / extract from zip file effort, not you delete effort, which is the part you are asking about.

***Yet what you are asking for it appears to be a duplicate*** of this discussion and answer.

[Remove files from .zip file with Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20269202/remove-files-from-zip-file-with-powershell)

You are also already calling the System.IO.Compression name space, so the System.IO.Compression.Filesystem has a update and delete method.

Example: (ignore / delete the pause - it's just there so one can see the result at each stage.)

```
# Zip file path
$zip = 'D:\Temp\MyFile.zip'

# Instantiate the .Net namespace
add-type -AssemblyName 'System.IO.Compression.filesystem'

# Remove a file from a zip archive
foreach ($z in $zip)
{
    # Open the zip for updating
    $tempz = [io.compression.zipfile]::Open($z,'Update')

    "`nShow all files in the zip"
    $tempz.Entries
    Pause

    "`nDelete a specific file"
    ($tempz.Entries | Where FullName -Match 'Test.clixml').Delete()
    Pause

    "`nValidate remove"
    $tempz.Entries
    Pause

    # Clean up / close the zip
    $tempz.Dispose()
}


Show all files in the zip


Archive            : System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive
CompressedLength   : 69
ExternalAttributes : 32
FullName           : newfile.txt
LastWriteTime      : 30-Sep-18 20:52:08 -07:00
Length             : 116
Name               : newfile.txt

Archive            : System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive
CompressedLength   : 41438
ExternalAttributes : 32
FullName           : ps-gps.xml
LastWriteTime      : 02-Oct-18 19:29:44 -07:00
Length             : 767464
Name               : ps-gps.xml

Archive            : System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive
CompressedLength   : 45
ExternalAttributes : 32
FullName           : MyFile.txt
LastWriteTime      : 30-Sep-18 23:31:08 -07:00
Length             : 55
Name               : MyFile.txt

Archive            : System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive
CompressedLength   : 132
ExternalAttributes : 32
FullName           : Test.clixml
LastWriteTime      : 02-Oct-18 17:26:00 -07:00
Length             : 202
Name               : Test.clixml

Press Enter to continue...: 

Delete a specific file
Press Enter to continue...: 

Validate remove
Archive            : System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive
CompressedLength   : 69
ExternalAttributes : 32
FullName           : newfile.txt
LastWriteTime      : 30-Sep-18 20:52:08 -07:00
Length             : 116
Name               : newfile.txt

Archive            : System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive
CompressedLength   : 41438
ExternalAttributes : 32
FullName           : ps-gps.xml
LastWriteTime      : 02-Oct-18 19:29:44 -07:00
Length             : 767464
Name               : ps-gps.xml

Archive            : System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive
CompressedLength   : 45
ExternalAttributes : 32
FullName           : MyFile.txt
LastWriteTime      : 30-Sep-18 23:31:08 -07:00
Length             : 55
Name               : MyFile.txt

Press Enter to continue...:
```

***Update as per the OP request / multiple files and code merge***

The number of zip files you may have to deal with, is really not a concern.
Pass as many as you have.

What you did not say is, how are you getting these zip file names. Meaning via
Get-ChildItem, or from some text file, the searching for them using the same cmdlet.

Either way the process is the same.

If I doctor your function directly, fixing some stuff along the way.
Try this...

```
function Expand-ZipFilesWithCleanUp
{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    [Alias('ezc')]

    Param
    (
        [string[]]$ZipFiles,
        [string]$Outdir,
        [string] $FilenameToRemove
    )

    # Instantiate the .Net namespace
    add-type -AssemblyName 'System.IO.Compression.filesystem'

    "The number of zip files passed in was $($ZipFiles.Count)"

    # Remove unwanted files
    foreach ($ZipFile in $ZipFiles)
    {
        # Open the zip for updating
        $ProcessZipFile = [io.compression.zipfile]::Open($ZipFile,'Update')

        "`nShow all files in the zip"
        $ProcessZipFile.Entries | Out-GridView -PassThru

        "`nDeleting unwanted file $FilenameToRemove from $ZipFile"
        ($ProcessZipFile.Entries | Where FullName -Match $FilenameToRemove).Delete()

        "`nValidate remove"
        $ProcessZipFile.Entries | Out-GridView -PassThru

        # Clean up / close the zip
        $ProcessZipFile.Dispose()
    }

    #//Begin unzip code



    #//End unzip code

}
Expand-ZipFilesWithCleanUp -ZipFiles (Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp' -Filter '*.zip').FullName -FilenameToRemove 'Test.clixml'
```

Again, those..

```
$ProcessZipFile.Entries | Out-GridView -PassThru
```

… lines are not needed, they are just a way to pop a dialog to show you what is happening in zip before and after the delete or the given file.

All you have to do now is add in your other code in the space provided.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I will change my function to add some lines of your code (I.e: delete code, validate the remove and clean/close the zip). I will let you know the outcome. Thanks again and I really appreciate your help.

Comment: No worries, and if it resolves your use case, be sure to mark this as the accepted answer for the benefit of others finding themselves in a similar need.

Comment: I will definitly do it.

Comment: Hi, I took some lines of your code and used into the function. I changed a little bit but it did not work for me. It displays an error and below is the error i received. You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At E:\PowershellScript\test2.ps1:34 char:5
+     ($tempz.Entries | Where FullName -Match 'abc.txt').Delete()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: The issue I have here is that I have 22 zip files to be extracted in 22 folders.  In your example you have only  1 folder and 1 zip file. How will I use your code to do with more than 1 zip file and 1 folder? Please help me out here?

Comment: Just create a list / array of you zipfile paths and pass them in, just as I did with one.

Comment: Ok Thank you. The Array will be huge because it will contain 22 zip files. Is it possible to put the delete method into my function? If it is possible could you please let me know how?  I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the function function Expand-ZipFilesWithCleanUp. What is the Alias 'ezc' stand for? could you please explain to me? Thank you!
Expand-ZipFilesWithCleanUp {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    [Alias('ezc')]

    Param
    (
        [string[]]$ZipFiles,
        [string]$Outdir,
        [string] $FilenameToRemove
    )

Comment: No worries. As for 'esc', it just alias. Most cmdlets/Functions have short names / Aliases you can use. For example dir or ls is the alias for Get-ChildItem. Of course you can create your own as long as they don't collide with an existing one. They must be unique. Your can see all aliases using the Get-Alias cmdlet or its parameter aliases using this one-liner --- (Get-Command Get-ChildItem).Parameters.Values | where aliases | select Name, Aliases

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response. I really do appreciate it. I have use your old code using a list of the zip files and it worked well. If i want to add more filenames to remove I guess i add names separating with a comma. ( I.e: ('abc', 'cde', 'efg').delete(). Am I correct?

Comment: You are correct, or better to say create a file to list the names, in a csv and read in that file. using Import-Csv. It's up to you.

Comment: I have almost finished my project when an error appears. The ZIP files I receive each day also contain today's date. For example:
Dept1.zipfile1.DT181011, Dept2.zipfile.2.DT181011  etc…. I formatted the date as follows: `$TodaysDate = (Get-Date).ToString('DTyyMMdd')`. When I build my list, it did not work. Here is my list: `$zip = ('c:\temp\ Dept1.zipfile1.$TodaysDate’, 'c:\temp\ Dept2.zipfile2.$TodaysDate’)`. It did not understand the variable $TodaysDate. How do I fix it. Thanks

Comment: If, for example, I set the date instead of the $ TodaysDate variable, the code works. But I do not want to put the date since tomorrow when I receive the files it will be another date.
How can I run my code with the variable $ TodaysDate?

Comment: The other thing I've notice is that if I want to remove more files, it does not remove. For 1 file to remove, it does work but it did not work more than one file. I do it as follows: `($tempz.Entries | Where FullName -Match ('abc.txt’,'cde.txt’,’efg.txt’).Delete()`. How should I fix that? Thank you

Comment: here is the code: `$zip = ('c:\temp\ Dept1.zipfile1.$TodaysDate’, 'c:\temp\ Dept2.zipfile2.$TodaysDate’)` `add-type -AssemblyName 'System.IO.Compression.filesystem'` `foreach ($z in $zip)`
   `{` `$tempz = [io.compression.zipfile]::Open($z,'Update')` `$tempz.Entries` `($tempz.Entries | Where FullName -Match ('abc.txt',’cde.txt’,’efg.txt’)).Delete()` `$tempz.Entries` `$tempz.Dispose()`

Comment: `$zip = Get-ChildItem c:\temp -Filter *nightly* `  `add-type -AssemblyName 'System.IO.Compression.filesystem' `  `foreach ($z in $zip){` `Write-Verbose "Updating $($z.name)" -Verbose` `$tempz = [io.compression.zipfile]::Open($z.FullName,'Update')` `$entry = $tempz.Entries | Where-Object{$_.fullname -match 'abc.txt'} ` `foreach ($e in $entry){` `$e.Delete()}` `$tempz.Dispose()
}`

Comment: I still have problem to remove more than 1 file

Comment: It finally worked. I use Expand-ZipFilesWithCleanUp function and everything works fine. Thank again and again. Case closed.