# VBS delete folder from Zipped folder

Tags: vbscript, zip

I am trying to use a VBScript to delete a folder that is zipped. The zip file has other folders and files as well.

Edit begin: the base code is from: [How to delete files from zip with VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20130123/how-to-delete-files-from-zip-with-vbscript/20147320#20147320)
end edit

Here is a localized sample of the script I tried deleting it with:

```
zipfile = "D:\testFolder\zippers\TestIt\New folder\your.zip"
foldername   = "New folder"
destination     = "D:\testFolder\zippers\TestIt\New folder"

Set app = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
For Each f In app.NameSpace(zipfile).Items
  If f.Name = foldername Then
    app.Namespace(destination).MoveHere f, FOF_NOCONFIRMATION
  End If
Next

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
fso.DeleteFolder fso.BuildPath(destination, foldername), True
```

Sadly, the folder in the ZIP remains. So the MoveHere seems like a CopyHere instead... weird

Can Anybody help?
PS: there is no delete-folder tag, just a delete-file one...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57490063/deleting-a-folder-from-a-zip-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be nice if you gave proper attribution when you're copying [someone else's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20147320/1630171).

With that said, it doesn't look like the `Shell.Application` object is capable of removing folders from a zip archive. Calling `MoveFile` on a folder moves all files from that nested folder out of the archive, but leaves an empty (sub)folder tree.

To remove the nested folder entirely you need to use 3rd party tools like [7-zip](http://7-zip.org/):

```
Function qq(s) : qq = """" & s & """" : End Function

Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sh.Run "C:\path\to\7z.exe d " & qq(zipfile) & " " & qq(foldername), 0, True
```

Comment: Sorry about that. You are right, I just didn't remember where i got the base code from, before starting to tamper with it...
Thanks for he tip, but sadly i'm trying to do this without any 3rd party program, otherwise i would just use 7zip. Oh well, than challenge impossible ;) Thanks for both.